# Can I get the element from a list that is not currently iterating?

Tags: python

If I want to iterate through a list with a for loop, I can do something like:

```
elements = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for element in elements:
    print(element)
```

and it will output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

But I am curious, is there any ways that I can have the loop tell me what is not currently being iterated?
For example:
when `element` is `1`, it can output a list that looks like this `[2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`, and when the loop goes on, each round it will output something like:
`[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
`[1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
`[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10]`
`[1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10]`
`[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]`
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10]`
`[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10]`
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10]`
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]`
`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to get the index of each element, remove the current index from a copy of the list, and print the rest.

Comment: So you want to skip particular entries with each iteration? Sounds like a job for `filter()`.

Comment: if elements = [1,2,1], you would presumably want [2,1], [1,1], [1,2] so filtering on index, not value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `enumerate(<iterable>)` and print the two parts of the list, skipping the relevant element.

```
elements = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
for i, element in enumerate(elements):
    print(elements[:i] + elements[i+1:])
```

(Note how you won't get an IndexError, since it's a slice. `elements[i+1]` would result in an IndexError; a slice will yield an empty list.)

---

A solution without `enumerate()`, and with `filter()`:

```
for element in elements:
    print(list(filter(lambda x: x != element, elements)))
```

(You'll need `list(...)`, unfortunately, since `filter()` is evaluated lazily, that is, it will only yield the elements if it's actually iterated over. `print()` doesn't do that, but `list()` does.)

This is roughly the same as some other solutions shown here, which use a list comprehension. Some people prefer filter, but I think it's deemed slightly more Pythonic to use a list comprehension. But very much a personal preference:

```
for element in elements:
    print([item for item in elements if item != element])
```

**A big caveat to the non-enumeration methods**: this only works when the list values are unique, since they compare *values*, not the list index. If there are duplicate items in the list, the output likely won't be what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much. `enumerate` wooks perfectly. And thank you for your detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

use enumerate like below:

```
for i, element in enumerate(elements):
    not_iterated = [x for j,x in enumerate(elements) if j!=i]
    print(not_iterated)
```

this would be output:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an auxiliary `set` object to check the difference:

```
elements = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
el_set = set(elements)

for el in elements:
    print(el_set - set([el]))
```

---

```
{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
{1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
{1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

Comment: But *only* when the items are unique; *and* the output order is undetermined.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare by *value* as opposed to *index* (note that there's no distinction in a list of unique items, so if you're not sure which you want, you need to consider what you'd want the result to be in a list like `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`), you can skip the `enumerate` and just do a list comprehension that gives you all items that don't equal the current one:

```
>>> elements = range(1, 11)
>>> for element in elements:
...     print([i for i in elements if i != element])
...
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```